# React open modal window on click in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the basic component modal component of react - https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to open the modal from another parent that has the modal imported.

Component CountryPopup

```js
export default class CountryPopup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modalIsOpen: this.props.isShowModal,
          popupName: (myIsSet(this.props, "data.name")) ? this.props.data.name : 'CountryPopup',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof window.dataLayer != "undefined" && this.props.isShowModal) {
            window.dataLayer.push({
                "event":"show popup",
                'eventCategory': 'popup',
                'eventAction': 'show',
                'eventLabel': this.state.popupName,
            });
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.closeModal();
    }

    closeModal() {
       .....
    }

    afterOpenModal = () => {
        document.body.classList.add("overflow-hide");
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.modalIsOpen);

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    typeof window != "undefined" &&
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                        onAfterOpen={() => this.afterOpenModal()}
                        contentLabel="This is for testing"
                        ariaHideApp={false}
                        className={{
                            base: 'myReactModal dynamic-popup-myReactModal',
                            afterOpen: 'myReactModal_after-open',
                            beforeClose: 'myReactModal_before-close'
                        }}
                        overlayClassName={ {
                            base: 'myOverlayClass dynamic-popup-myOverlayClass',
                            afterOpen: 'myOverlayClass_after-open',
                            beforeClose: 'myOverlayClass_before-close'
                        }}
                    >
                        ......
                    </Modal>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

another Component HomeView - in this component want to open modal window onclick

```js
class HomeView extends Component {

        // onShowModal = () => {
        //     // <CountryPopup isShowModal={true}  />
        //     console.log("You clicked me");
        //     // this.setState({showModal:true})
        // }

    render () {
        var app = this.props.app;
        var data = this.props.home.data || {};
        let dfp = this.props.dfp;
        let outbrainAds = dfp.outbrain;

        let currentUrl = this.props.user.baseUrl + this.props.location.pathname.replace("/", "");


        return (
            <BaseLayout match={this.props.match} isCallWallpaper={true} fromHome={true} />

            <CountryPopup isShowModal={true}  />
            
            
            }
            
    export default HomeView;
```

currently, popup is visible on load

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are trying to make component "controlled" AND "uncontrolled". You must have the state either in one of the component or the other. You can't do both.

Usually, it's the parent component which holds the state.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  }

  toggleModal =() => this.setState(state => ({open: !state.open}))

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <button value="Toggle Modal" onClick={this.toggleModal}/>
      <Modal opened={this.state.open} toggleModal={this.toggleModal}/>
    </div>)
}

class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <button value="Toggle Modal" onClick={this.props.toggleModal}/>
      {this.props.opened && <ReactModal ... />}
    </div>)
  }
}
```

In this example, both button in both components will toggle the modal

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel its good idea to manage modal state in Child component and parent component both. But You can use the below code to pass modal state from parent.

```
class HomeView extends Component {
  state = {
     showModal: false
  }

  onShowModal = () => {
    this.setState({showModal: true})
  }

  render () {
    var app = this.props.app;
    var data = this.props.home.data || {};
    let dfp = this.props.dfp;
    let outbrainAds = dfp.outbrain;

    let currentUrl = this.props.user.baseUrl + this.props.location.pathname.replace("/", "");


    return (
      <BaseLayout match={this.props.match} isCallWallpaper={true} fromHome={true} />

      <CountryPopup isShowModal={this.state.showModal} />
    )
}
```

export default HomeView;

Country Popup

```
export default class CountryPopup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modalIsOpen: props.isShowModal,
          popupName: (myIsSet(props, "data.name")) ? props.data.name : 'CountryPopup',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof window.dataLayer != "undefined" && this.props.isShowModal) {
            window.dataLayer.push({
                "event":"show popup",
                'eventCategory': 'popup',
                'eventAction': 'show',
                'eventLabel': this.state.popupName,
            });
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.closeModal();
    }

    closeModal() {
       .....
    }

    afterOpenModal = () => {
        document.body.classList.add("overflow-hide");
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.modalIsOpen);

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    typeof window != "undefined" &&
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                        onAfterOpen={() => this.afterOpenModal()}
                        contentLabel="This is for testing"
                        ariaHideApp={false}
                        className={{
                            base: 'myReactModal dynamic-popup-myReactModal',
                            afterOpen: 'myReactModal_after-open',
                            beforeClose: 'myReactModal_before-close'
                        }}
                        overlayClassName={ {
                            base: 'myOverlayClass dynamic-popup-myOverlayClass',
                            afterOpen: 'myOverlayClass_after-open',
                            beforeClose: 'myOverlayClass_before-close'
                        }}
                    >
                        ......
                    </Modal>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set PROP and then pass to your modal popup component as :

```
    <CountryPopup isShowModal={this.state.showModal}  />
```

Also, do your popup related operations in parent component like `showModal(...)` , `hideModal(...)`

And in your modal popup component you can use prop `showModal` passed from parent component and also can handle click/toggle action.